# Jquery prevent page reload on post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following pages **edit_profile.php** that is the page where the form is, and **ajax/update_profile.php** that is the page where data is sent via ajax.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#update_profile").click(function() {
                  var updateprofile = $("#update_profile_form").serialize();
                     $.post(
                            "ajax/update_profile.php",
                            updateprofile
                     ).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Successfully submitted!");
                            $("#result").html(data);


                     }).fail(function () {
                              //alert("Error submitting forms!");
                     })
              });
            });
        </script>
```

The problem is that after the ajax response it just reload the  **edit_profile.php** page again like **F5** on browser, what to do for the page do not reload?

Comment: By any chance is `$("#update_profile")` in a `<form>` with the `type` of `submit`?  If that's the case you need to `preventDefault()`

Comment: It's just a normal form, since the jquery handle the post data, `<form method="post"` is not used to send data it's all made in the jquery code

Comment: Show us your `HTML` please

Comment: I'd also be interested in the data that's being loaded into the #result element.

Comment: #result is the php validation message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
 $("#update_profile").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); //to prevent do action
```

Comment: Very cool it's working, but now I am facing another problem, is there anyway to refresh without reload? because it updates user profile in database but it's not loaded in click I need to refresh the page but without reload

Comment: Do You mean refresh the form or the page?

Comment: yes, the page it self but without seems to be reloaded

Comment: i think refresh is the same reload!

Comment: Do you want to refresh  the page with the new values?

Comment: exactly, I want to refresh the page with the new values

Comment: something like refresh full page body but do not reload the page

Comment: write in your done function console.log(data) to see data in your console-devtools
so if data return user or any value handle it by
data.user.name and  $('.name').text(data.user.name)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196601/discussion-between-developer-and-mohamed-hassan).